# How do I add pagination to my list of divs

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So I have a partial view that looks like this

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="container-1">
        <div class="box-img">
            <img src="@item.ProductImage" />
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <h3>@item.ItemName</h3>
            <p>@item.SubTitle</p>
        </div>

        <div class="box-button">
            <p>@item.SKU</p>
        </div>

        <div class="box-button">
            <p class="mt-3 mr-2">$@item.Price</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Export</button>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

And the way I'm implementing that partial view is on my index.cshtml like so

```
<div id="itemsss">
    <partial name="_Item" />
</div>
```

Now in order to make sure that only the partial view updates dynamically without having to manually refresh the entire page I'm using ajax like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(CheckAvailability, 500);
});

function CheckAvailability() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Dashboard/CheckChange",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        mimeType: "text/html",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $('#itemsss').load("/Dashboard/ReturnItems");
                console.log("Updated!");
            }
            else {
                console.log("Failed!");
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Where the idea is that it will fetch the data every .5 seconds whether there has been a change or not, again just to keep it updates. It loads all the partial view divs into the div with the id of itemsss which you can see in the index.cshtml

And the action it's fetching would be this

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ReturnItems()
{
    Items = new List<EbayProduct>();
    using (var ctx = new UserContext())
    {
        Items = ctx.Users.Include(x => x.Items).Where(x => x.Username == "Admin").FirstOrDefault().Items;
    }
    return PartialView("_Item", Items);
}
```

And this works great, it keeps it updated and what not.

The issue is that it adds it all in one big list, where as I want to start using pagination once it hits 7 or more items in the collection. I honestly have no idea how to do that. How would I properly implement pagination to something like this? I had bootstrap pagination in mind but I just don't see how I would do that.

Here is another issue.. Since it updates every .5 seconds it would update the first page over and over again.

I feel as if this is almost impossible to accomplish. What's a good approach for this?

Comment: There are pagination plugins around you can use and easily find on web

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to create a PaginatedList which will get the right item based on the pageindex and pagesize. Then you could use this class to get the right item based on client returned pageindex and pagesize.

PaginatedList:

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex > 1);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
        }
    }

    public static   PaginatedList<T> CreateAsync(
        IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count =  source.Count();
        var items =   source.Skip(
            (pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize).ToList();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

Controller:

Notice: I used a list as the DataSource, you could directly use the selected result items.

```
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        public List<EabyProduct> DataSource = new List<EabyProduct>() {
         new EabyProduct { ItemName="test1" , SubTitle="Title1", ProductImage=" image1" , Price=1 },
         new EabyProduct { ItemName="test2" , SubTitle="Title1", ProductImage=" image1" , Price=1 },
         new EabyProduct { ItemName="test3" , SubTitle="Title1", ProductImage=" image1" , Price=1 },
         new EabyProduct { ItemName="test4" , SubTitle="Title1", ProductImage=" image1" , Price=1 },
         new EabyProduct { ItemName="test5" , SubTitle="Title1", ProductImage=" image1" , Price=1 },
            new EabyProduct { ItemName="test6" , SubTitle="Title1", ProductImage=" image1" , Price=1 },

         new EabyProduct { ItemName="test7" , SubTitle="Title1", ProductImage=" image1" , Price=1 },
         new EabyProduct { ItemName="test8" , SubTitle="Title1", ProductImage=" image1" , Price=1 },
new EabyProduct { ItemName="test9" , SubTitle="Title1", ProductImage=" image1" , Price=1 },

         new EabyProduct { ItemName="test10" , SubTitle="Title1", ProductImage=" image1" , Price=1 },
         new EabyProduct { ItemName="test11" , SubTitle="Title1", ProductImage=" image1" , Price=1 },
new EabyProduct { ItemName="test12" , SubTitle="Title1", ProductImage=" image1" , Price=1 }

        };

        public const int pagesize = 3;
        
        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            ViewBag.DefaultProdct = PaginatedList<EabyProduct>.CreateAsync(DataSource.AsQueryable(), 1, pagesize);

            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ReturnItems(int pageindex)
        {
            //Items = new List<EbayProduct>();
            //using (var ctx = new UserContext())
            //{
            //    Items = ctx.Users.Include(x => x.Items).Where(x => x.Username == "Admin").FirstOrDefault().Items;
            //}
            

            //I directly create a test list datasrouce 
            return PartialView("_Item", PaginatedList<EabyProduct>.CreateAsync(DataSource.AsQueryable(), pageindex, pagesize));
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CheckChange()
        {
            //Checklogic

            return Ok("OK");
        }
    }
```

Index :

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "View";
}

<h1>View</h1>

<div id="itemsss">
    <partial name="_Item" model="ViewBag.DefaultProdct" />
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(CheckAvailability, 1000);
    });

    function CheckAvailability() {
        var currentpageindex = $("#pageindex").val();
        console.log(currentpageindex);
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/Product/CheckChange",
            success: function (rew) {
                console.log("Updated!");
                $('#itemsss').load("/Product/ReturnItems?pageindex=" + currentpageindex);
            }
        });
    };
    function Pre() {
        var currentpageindex = $("#pageindex").val();

        console.log(currentpageindex);
        $('#itemsss').load("/Product/ReturnItems?pageindex=" + (parseInt(currentpageindex) - 1));
    }

    function Next() {
        var currentpageindex = $("#pageindex").val();

        console.log(currentpageindex);
        $('#itemsss').load("/Product/ReturnItems?pageindex=" + (parseInt(currentpageindex) + 1));
    }


</script>
```

_Item partial view:

```
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@

@model MVCRelatedIssue.PaginatedList<MVCRelatedIssue.Models.EabyProduct>



<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="container-1">
        <div class="box-img">
            <img src="@item.ProductImage" />
        </div>

        <div class="body">
            <h3>@item.ItemName</h3>
            <p>@item.SubTitle</p>
        </div>

        <div class="box-button">
            <p>@item.SKU</p>
        </div>

        <div class="box-button">
            <p class="mt-3 mr-2">$@item.Price</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Export</button>
        </div>

    </div>
}

@{
    var prevDisabled = Model.HasPreviousPage ? "" : "disabled";
    var nextDisabled = Model.HasNextPage ? "" : "disabled";

}

<input  id="pageindex" type="hidden" value="@Model.PageIndex"/>

<hr/>

<a  
   class="btn btn-primary @prevDisabled" id="Pre" onclick="Pre()" >
    Previous
</a>
<a   
   class="btn btn-primary @nextDisabled" id="Next" onclick="Next()" >
    Next
</a>
```

Result:

[image]